# What is the limit/cap on the usage of Bing maps in Reporting Services (SSRS)?

Tags: reporting-services, bing-maps, reporting-services-2012

I am working on SSRS report that potentially will be viewed by 1000 users a day. I'm concerned that Bing will ban an IP address of the organization if it receives thousands queries a day. I have looked for answer on MSDN & Google without any success.

I want to know what the usage limit is of Bing Maps in SSRS.

Comment: What is wrong with the question? I want to be proactive & find out about the limit before getting an error on production server that Bing limit is reached.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this question. I think it is valid. Wonder why people are voting it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bing Maps will not ban the IP address at this volume. Bing Maps receives billions of requests a day. The usage from 1,000 users won't really be an issue. The only real limit is what your database server can handle in terms of processing these requests.